# Windows RPC object marshalling

Tags: c++, com, rpc, midl

I'm trying to use Windows RPC for communcation between two processes (C/C++, 32bit, Win7).

I've followed the example here [Instruction to RPC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4837/Introduction-to-RPC-Part?msg=4458017#xx4458017xx) and successfully got RPC to work. Now I have difficulties getting the proxy / stub thing to work too.

The IDL file looks like this:

```
[ uuid(3cb112c0-688a-4611-83b6-31d33d87ea28), object ]
interface IDemo : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT ThisIsAMethod([in, string] const char* test);
}

[ uuid(60ad6a21-ba49-483a-b0a2-faa5187b8299), version(1.0),
  implicit_handle(handle_t hDemoBinding)]
interface IDemoRPC
{
    void SimpleTest();
    void GetDemo([out] IDemo** service);
    void Shutdown();
}
```

I can invoke `SimpleTest()` remotely on the server from the client. Works just fine. But `GetDemo()` gives me an access violation when the server 'returns' something else than `NULL`.

Here's what I've done:

- Build a DLL based on the generated demo_i.c, demo_p.c, dlldata.c. With `REGISTER_PROXY_DLL` set and a def file containing the five private entries. I've registered it with `regsvr32` (the one from WOW64).
- Created a `DemoImpl` class in the server process that extends `IDemo` and implements `ThisIsAMethod` as well as `AddRef` and friends.
- Implemented `GetDemo(IDemo** service)` with a one-liner `*service = new DemoImpl();`

When I invoke `GetDemo` from the client process, the *server* process terminates with an access violation (0x00000014). The stacktrace shows that it happens in a separate thread deep within rpcrt4.

I would have expected that the thing returns a proxy to the client.

I have the suspicion that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here. For one thing, I can't find an example where instances of interface-objects are created with `new`. There always some some magic with `CoGetClassObject` or something. No clue how these functions should know where to find the implementation.

Comment: @noxmetus no I don't. I just implemented DemoImpl it as a straight forward c++ class.

Comment: How does the implementation of `IDemoRPC` itself get instantiated?
I wonder if the methods of IDemoRPC shouldn't return `HRESULT`.
What's the initial ref count of `DemoImpl` when you pass it out of `GetDemo()`?

Comment: IDemoRPC does not have object semantics (notice the absence of the "object" attribute). It cannot be instantiated. It is not a COM thing at all, therefore no refcount and no HRESULT requirement.

Comment: Ah.  Creating and connecting a COM object via plain RPC is something I'd never heard of. Is that really supported?  Perhaps there's no COM infrastructure involved (and it should be).  Where is your access violation -- in the client or server?  Perhaps RPC is simply copying the pointer value, rather than establishing proxy/stub for marshalling.  And the pointer is of course invalid in the client address space.

Comment: I think the normal way to do this is the server would register a COM class factory with associated CLSID, and the client would use e.g. [CoCreateInstance()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a proxy to an instance of the thing created by the factory, i.e. the IDemo (Impl).

Yes, the class factory and the thing it creates can be instantiated with `new`.